# How to fetch data using Select query twice from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to retrieve the latest txn from this SQL query. Right now my query compares all the txn from `txn.txn`. Instead I want to grab the latest txn. I'm trying to do something like this, not sure how to do another select statement for this query.

```
(SELECT TOP (1) 
     [T].[TransactionDateTime] 
 FROM 
     TXN.TXN 
 WHERE
     [T].[TransactionDateTime] <= DATEADD(DD, -@DaysSinceLastVisit, GETUTCDATE()) 
 ORDER BY
     [T].[TransactionDateTime] DESC)
```

Not sure how to use another Select statement for this query.

Comment: Yes SQL Server (MS SQL) code

Comment: *I want to grab the latest txn.* `ROW_NUMBER()` in CTE and `WHERE rn=1` in outer query.

Comment: SELECT  TOP (1) [T].[TransactionDateTime] FROM TXN.TXN where 
                     [T].[TransactionDateTime]<= DATEADD(DD, - @DaysSinceLastVisit, GETUTCDATE()) 
                     order by  [T].[TransactionDateTime] DESC 
So It will return similar data like this ?Sorry for asking again i'm still  nob level in SQL

Comment: If you need in only one output row from your query then sorting+limiting is correct.

Comment: I still need all the user back ,somehow I will need to grab latest txn for this condition ```(
                       [T].[TransactionDateTime]<= DATEADD(DD, - @DaysSinceLastVisit, GETUTCDATE())
                    )```

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), especially p.p. 5 and 3.

Comment: Aside... [NOLOCK Is Bad And You Probably Shouldn’t Use It](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2021/11/nolock-is-bad-and-you-probably-shouldnt-use-it/).